# Using Multiple AND (&&) Operator Did Not Work (PHP)

Tags: php

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `scadatel_spin`.`spin` WHERE `tanggal_berangkat`='$tanggal_berangkat' AND `tanggal_kembali`='$tanggal_kembali' ORDER BY `id`");
$data2=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$cek1=$data2['pelaksana1'];
$cek2=$data2['pelaksana2'];
$cek3=$data2['pelaksana3'];
$cek4=$data2['pelaksana4'];

if(($cek1==$pelaksana1) && ($cek2==$pelaksana2) && ($cek3==$pelaksana3) && ($cek4==$pelaksana4)){
header('location: gagal_input.php');exit;       
}
if(($cek1==$pelaksana1) && ($cek2==$pelaksana2) && ($cek3==$pelaksana4) && ($cek4==$pelaksana3)){
header('location: gagal_input.php');exit;       
}
if(($cek1==$pelaksana1) && ($cek2==$pelaksana3) && ($cek3==$pelaksana4) && ($cek4==$pelaksana2)){
header('location: gagal_input.php');exit;       
}
if(($cek1==$pelaksana1) && ($cek2==$pelaksana3) && ($cek3==$pelaksana2) && ($cek4==$pelaksana4)){
header('location: gagal_input.php');exit;       
}
if(($cek1==$pelaksana1) && ($cek2==$pelaksana4) && ($cek3==$pelaksana2) && ($cek4==$pelaksana3)){
header('location: gagal_input.php');exit;       
}
if(($cek1==$pelaksana1) && ($cek2==$pelaksana4) && ($cek3==$pelaksana3) && ($cek4==$pelaksana2)){
header('location: gagal_input.php');exit;       
}
```

If I used three AND operators, It worked properly.

But, If I used more than three AND operators, It could not work properly.

Anybody help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: you mean three "AND" in sql query? or in php conditions?

Comment: wow that is a real, mess I would rework that with nesting....  You know those `($cek1==$pelaksana1) && ` inner `()` are not needed.

Comment: you need nest again with couple `(($cek1==$pelaksana1) && ($cek2==$pelaksana2)) && (($cek3==$pelaksana3) && ($cek4==$pelaksana4))`

Comment: I dont see the point as they all go to the same url `gagal_input.php` you could maybe simplify it by checking the reverse  `!=` instead?

Comment: I mean three AND operators in PHP not in SQL. I had already tried remove this one (). But, it still did not work for me.

Comment: by the way there is no need to so many  "()" when all operators are AND

Comment: i think there is no problem with AND phrases.the datandoes not match any of the above conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This might work better for what you're trying to do. I am on my phone so please excuse any errors, but pretty much you want to put them all in an array and test if the first value matches the rest:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `scadatel_spin`.`spin` WHERE `tanggal_berangkat`='$tanggal_berangkat' AND `tanggal_kembali`='$tanggal_kembali' ORDER BY `id`");
$data2=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$cek1=$data2['pelaksana1'];
$cek2=$data2['pelaksana2'];
$cek3=$data2['pelaksana3'];
$cek4=$data2['pelaksana4'];

$verifyData = array();

$verifyData[] = $cek1;
$verifyData[] = $cek2;
$verifyData[] = $cek3;
$verifyData[] = $cek4;

$allMatch = true;

$firstValue = current($verifyData);
foreach ($verifyData as $val) {
        if ($firstValue !== $val) {
            $allMatch = false;
        }
}

if(!$allMatch){
header('location: gagal_input.php');
exit; 
}
```